# Which Android elements should I use to create two dynamic Lists?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, fragmentpageradapter

I want to create an Android screen that has a List that scrolls from left to right (Items are more intricate than example below), and onClick() of a Horizontal Item, it displays items vertically (ie. Item 1, Item 2, Item 3).

I'm a little confused as to which elements should be used to create this screen?

[image: Android Screen]

Comment: What about PageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do something like this :

ScrollView

---- RecyclerView (Horizontal)

---- RecyclerView (Vertical)

Comment: Would you use any of the TabLayout and ViewPager classes or straight up RecyclerView for both?

Comment: TabLayout and ViewPager can do the same. Up to your need.
P/s: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Answer (score 1):

These can be done using recyclerview and toolbar.

Try this link its straight forward: :)

https://medium.com/@dan1ve/android-howto-material-design-tabs-scrolling-like-in-google-play-music-12273ce07bc

Comment: Do you know if I can create intricate, custom layouts in the horizontal view with Pagers and TabLayout? Or should I use RecyclerView?